# Does Android Studio not offer hot deployment of apps?

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I make even the smallest change to my code, I have to stop the AVD and restart it to see any change. Is this normal? Does Android Studio not offer hot deployment of apps?

Comment: That's not normal. Normally, you can run your app without restarting the AVD. Try to create a new AVD, or update your AVDs via SDK Manager

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was actually hoping I was just doing something wrong, as the machine I am using Android Studio on has absolutely no connection to the internet, whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does now in Android Studio 2.0, check out the [Instant Run](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) feature.

[image]

Comment: Is v 2.0 available for general download, or is it still in beta?

Comment: Weird ... on my Linux machine, when I launch my v 1.5 it says there is an update, but I don't have the option to update. I really don't want to download the entire binary just to install v 2.0.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that as well on my mac, I had to download the entire binary.

Comment: Rats ... well, I'll wait a week or so to see if I can upgrade. If not, then I'll just download the binaries too. Thanks for the input. Have a good day.

Comment: As a side note ... I just noticed that Android Studio v 2.0 requires Java 1.8, and I have only 1.7. That may be the issue.